# Ruby TCP chat server

Tags: ruby, tcp

Recently Iv'e been trying to program a simple TCP server to later build into a chat room. But every time I launch the server (`server.rb`), and then I try to use the client (`client.rb`) I get this error:

```
    Sam@ANDERSAMERPC C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Coding
    > client.rb
    C:/Users/Sam/Documents/Coding/client.rb:6:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "localhost" port 2001 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from C:/Users/Sam/Documents/Coding/client.rb:6:in `open'
    from C:/Users/Sam/Documents/Coding/client.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I am using CMD to run this and I've tried turning off firewall briefly.
Here is the code for both of the programs...

This is `server.rb`

```
    require 'socket'

    server = TCPServer.open(2000)   # Socket to listen on port 2000
    loop {
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send time to the client
          client.puts "Closing connection. Bye!"
        client.close
      end
    }
```

Here's `client.rb`:

```
    require 'socket'

    hostname = "localhost"
    port = 2000

    s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

    while line = s.gets   # Reads lines from socket
      puts line.chop      # And print with platform line terminator
    end

    s.close               # Close socket when done
```

(This code is from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm just so you know.)

Answer (score 0):

**I guess there are 2 options:**

1. Run your `server.rb` before `client.rb`.
2. Are you sure those are the exact same files that you are running. Because the error message says it can not connect to port `2001`, whereas in both of your files they refer to `2000`. Is it possible that you are editing and running different files? You will be surprised, how common this is here on SO :)